# Installed DRDB Utilities but there is no /dev/drbd0 device

Tags: ubuntu, drbd

Installed DRDB Utilities but there is no /dev/drbd0 device even after running the command `drbdadm create-md r0`. Is there a command to create /dev/drbd0 device?

Answer (score 3):

You have created the meta-data for the device, but you then must bring the DRBD resource/device "up". You can do this with either the command `drbdadm up r0`, or via the systemd unit file.

Please note that bringing the resource up will make the /dev/drbd0 device appear, but it will still be unusable until you promote it to primary. This is usually done via `drbdadm primary r0`, but the first time you must decide upon a sync source with `drbdadm primary r0 --force`.